# Is there any way to get the exact audio .wav from a .mp4 video? (same length and same duration)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, wav

I extracted .wav files from many short mp4 videos. (3-6 seconds) But the extracted xxx.wav can not be aligned with .mp4 videos in Premiere. Some videos are 1 frame, and some 2 frames behind.

I used ffmpeg as the following command line:

`ffmpeg -i xxx.mp4 xxx.wav`

I tried -async or -vsync, but not worked. Here is an example:
[1 frame shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bt2V.png)

Here is the source mp4 and the extracted wav:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BFS0JLCPqA3YDMIahlorXTaRTFTJaPfU?usp=share_link

Do you know what caused the problem? Is there any way to get the exact audio .wav from a .mp4 video? (Aligned with frame level) Thank you very much.

Comment: I find the .wav extracted by adobe audition is exactly right. So there must be some problems in ffmpeg.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Extract wavs from videos.